# How to rename jar file that's being published using Gradle with maven-publish and shadow plugins?

Tags: java, maven, gradle, maven-publish, gradle-shadow-plugin

Basically what I'm trying to do is publish a jar file to GitHub Packages with a certain name. What I have now is:

```
shadowJar {
    archiveFileName = "Some-Name-${parent.version}.${extension}"
}

publishing {

   ...

    publications {
        shadow(MavenPublication) { publication ->
            project.shadow.component(publication)
            artifactId = 'me.project'
            groupId = 'some-project'
            version = 1.1.0
            
        }
    }
}
```

But from this I get `some-project-1.1.0-all.jar`, I would like to get `some-project-1.1.0.jar` but cant seem to find the way how. Changing the `archiveFileName` in the `shadowJar` task doesn't seem to affect the `publishing` jar only the `build` jar.

Comment: I do still wonder how to change name to something completely different, not just removing the classifier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need to change the `archiveClassifier` of the `shadowJar` task. By default, this is configured as `all`.

- Point 5: https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow/blob/master/src/docs/getting-started/README.md#default-javagroovy-tasks
- https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow/blob/7.0.0/src/main/groovy/com/github/jengelman/gradle/plugins/shadow/ShadowJavaPlugin.groovy#L66

Something like:

```
tasks.shadowJar {
    archiveClassifier = ""
}
```

The `shadowJar` task [extends](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow/blob/7.0.0/src/main/groovy/com/github/jengelman/gradle/plugins/shadow/tasks/ShadowJar.java) of the [`Jar`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar.html) task type. By default, with the [Java plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar:archiveClassifier), `archiveClassifier` is configured as an empty String `""`. The Shadow plugin reconfigures its `shadowJar` task with `all`.

Comment: I managed to get it working but your example seems to be deprecated so I used `archiveClassifier.set('')` instead and it did the trick.